# Meaning of the statement, almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

what is the meaining of $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}P(\sup_{m \ge n} |X_m -X|>\epsilon) \to 0  $$ forall $\epsilon > 0.$ I found this statement , while trying to understand almost sure convergence , i.e $X_n \to X$ iff the above statement holds.

Comment: Could anyone suggest some good resources to study modes of convergence. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of random variable , then the probability that absolute value of  $|X_m-X|$ is greater than $\epsilon$ for any arbitrary is $0$ .

ie the supremum of the difference of $X_m$ to $X$ becomes very small as $n \to \infty$ .